# "divide" two pandas dataframe to create one dataframe

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have two dataframes for different times, with the same columns, each coulmn represnt a bacteria. each index represent a sample. It looks something like this, for e.g:

```
df_time0 = pd.DataFrame({'Bacteria1': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3],'Bacteria2': [0.2, 0.3, 0.4],\
                         'Bacteria3': [0.3, 0.4, 0.5],}, index=['T0subject001', 'T0subject010', 'T0subject200'])

df_time1 = pd.DataFrame({'Bacteria1': [0.15, 0.15, 0.4],'Bacteria2': [0.3, 0.35, 0.2],\
                         'Bacteria3': [0.3, 0.45, 0.6],}, index=['T1subject001', 'T1subject010', 'T1subject200'])
```

Now, I want to iterate over both df's, and create one df which is the individual ln ratio between time 1 and time 0.
desired output:

[image]

the indexes in my desired df would contain the subject ID without time.
the value `at.["subject001", "Bacteria1"] = ln(df_time1.at["T1subject001", "Bacteria1"]/df_time0.at["T0subject001", "Bacteria1"])`, etc..

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `Tx` in your indices, that will make it possible to align the indexes:

```
# let's remove the T0/T1 from the index
df_time0.index = df_time0.index.str[2:]
df_time1.index = df_time1.index.str[2:]

# perform a simple division
out = df_time1.div(df_time0, axis=0)

print(out)
```

Output:

```
            Bacteria1  Bacteria2  Bacteria3
subject001   1.500000   1.500000      1.000
subject010   0.750000   1.166667      1.125
subject200   1.333333   0.500000      1.200
```

With the natural logarithm:

```
import numpy as np

# assuming the indexes as already fixed
out = np.log(df_time1.div(df_time0.to_numpy(), axis=0))
```

Output:

```
            Bacteria1  Bacteria2  Bacteria3
subject001   0.405465   0.405465   0.000000
subject010  -0.287682   0.154151   0.117783
subject200   0.287682  -0.693147   0.182322
```

Comment: Thanks! can you modify your answer to use Ln instead of division, so the output would be identical to my output?

Answer (score 1):

Much like what @mozway states, but if you're confident in the alignment of your dataframes, then you can convert both dataframes to numpy arrays and divide and reapply indexing using dataframe constructor.

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame(df_time1.to_numpy() / df_time0.to_numpy(), 
                      index=df_time0.index.str[2:], 
                      columns=df_time0.columns)
df_out
```

Output:

```
            Bacteria1  Bacteria2  Bacteria3
subject001   1.500000   1.500000      1.000
subject010   0.750000   1.166667      1.125
subject200   1.333333   0.500000      1.200
```